# Rails: Include all of model A and only a subset of related model B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to understand the rails database API better. If I have the following models:

```
class Link
  has_many :votes
  belongs_to :user
end

class Vote
  belongs_to: link
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :links
  has_many :votes
end
```

I want to "eagerly" return a list of ALL links and for each link I want the votes where the user_id equals the current user. I tried this:

```
l = Link.all(:include => :votes, :conditions => { :votes => { :user_id => current_user.id}})
```

But that only returns a list of links for which the user has submitted a vote. I want it to return *all* the links and then only the votes for that user (or none if there are none). How can I do this with the include statement?

Comment: Which version of Rails is this?

Comment: "want it to return all the links **and then** only the votes for that user". Sounds like you are dealing with two separate queries

Comment: @depa 3.2 although I'm interested in the solution to version 4 as well. beautifulcoder Really? This can't be done in a single query? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: How about the links that do not have any votes? Do you want to pull those as well?

Comment: Yosep - Yes, all links should be pulled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reread the question a couple of times so please let me know if I'm confused about this. It sounds like you want to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  That will give you everything from the `links` table where the vote matches the user id, and every other link where there is no vote match with the curret user. Something like this:

```
Link.all(:include => :votes, 
:select=>"DISTINCT links.*",
:joins => "LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON links.id = votes.link_id AND votes.user_id = #{current_user.id}", 
:conditions=>"NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM votes WHERE votes.link_id = links.id) OR votes.user_id = #{current_user.id}")
```

Also, since you're already using Rails 3.2, you'll probably want to use the newer active record query methods, since I believe the old hash based finder methods are deprecate in Rails 4. So the same query would look like this:

```
Link.include(:votes)
.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON links.id = votes.link_id AND votes.user_id = #{current_user.id}")
.where("NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM votes WHERE votes.link_id = links.id) OR votes.user_id = #{current_user.id}")
.uniq.load
```

Regarding the conditions / where portion, that will create a dependent subquery that will cause the `Link` row to be rejected if it exists in the votes table (meaning SOMEBODY voted on it at one point), or if it does exist whether it is a vote by our specified user. The end result is you get any `Link` row that does not have any votes, or links with votes created by the specified user.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, the problem with this approach is that the associated `votes` rows are not eager loaded as required. After tooling around with this for about 2 hours now, I am nearly to the point of admitting that I do not believe it is possible to eager load the associated table with this kind of query.

If we ditch the `include` part (which seems to have no effect anyways), we **do** get back a collection of `Link` objects that have been voted on by the specified user, or nobody at all. The problem is when we invoke `.votes`, Rails happily makes **another call to the database** along the lines of `SELECT votes.* FROM votes WHERE votes.link_id = [the link id]`, which as you can see doesn't discriminate by user_id at that point.

The only solution I can think of is to properly quantify what you're looking for when invoking the association method. Something like this:

```
link.votes.where(:user_id=>current_user.id)
```

Which will yield a query like this:

```
SELECT votes.* FROM votes WHERE votes.link_id = [the link ID] AND user_id = [the user ID]
```

If anybody has a better solution, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your solution works when I do it directly in SQL, e.g. select links.title, votes.value from links left join votes on (links.id = votes.link_id AND votes.user_id = 5); But when I do your solution in rails and assign the value to l and then type l[0].votes I get [#<Vote id: 1, value: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: "2013-10-15 20:42:06", link_id: 1, user_id: 5>, #<Vote id: 3, value: 1, created_at: "2013-10-15 20:45:24", updated_at: "2013-10-15 20:45:24", link_id: 1, user_id: 4>] Which is returning votes from two different users.... Strange no?

Comment: @user1813867 crap. Yeah it's because of the AND votes.user_id part with the left join. I'm just in transit now so give me a couple of minutes and I'll figure it out

Comment: @user1813867 See my update...not exactly what you wanted, but at least its within the "rails" way of doing things. Hope it helps somewhat.

Comment: @user1813867 Updated the query. Let me know whether it works for you.