# How to select max(date) and group by client_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I got this working the way I want in pure sql:

```
select * from clients c 
    join insurance_providers p on c.id = p.client_id 
where p.effective_on = 
    (select max(effective_on) 
         from insurance_providers group by client_id having p.client_id = client_id)
and user_id = 2; #user_id =2 where 2 represents current_user.id
```

Here what I tried in the console:

```
Client.joins(:insurance_providers)
      .select('max(insurance_providers.effective_on)')
      .group(:client_id)
      .where('user_id = 2')
```

It promptly exploded in my face with:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `group' for Mon, 08 Jul 2013:Date

It looks like I'm just getting the date itself returned from the select statement. I need something like `"where effective_on = .select('max..."`

any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I'm getting closer with this:

```
InsuranceProvider.maximum(:effective_on, :group => 'client_id')
```

but I'm not sure how to join the clients table in to get all the info I need.
In the rails console, both of these:

```
Client.joins(:insurance_providers).maximum(:effective_on, :group => 'client_id')
Client.joins(:insurance_providers.maximum(:effective_on, :group => 'client_id'))
```

cause this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `group' for Mon, 08 Jul 2013:Date

UPDATE:

this is closer, but I need a having clause on the end - just not sure how to tie the inner table and outer table together (like in the sql: p.client_id = client_id):

```
insuranceProvider = InsuranceProvider.where("effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers group by client_id)")
  InsuranceProvider Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "insurance_providers".* FROM "insurance_providers" WHERE (effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers group by client_id))
PG::CardinalityViolation: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
: SELECT "insurance_providers".* FROM "insurance_providers"  WHERE (effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers group by client_id))
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::CardinalityViolation: ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
: SELECT "insurance_providers".* FROM "insurance_providers"  WHERE (effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers group by client_id))
```

UPDATE: here's some progress.
This seems to be what I need, but I don't know how to join it to the clients table:

```
InsuranceProvider.where("effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers p group by client_id having p.client_id = insurance_providers.client_id)")
```

This gives me the insurance_providers grouped by the client_id. I need to join to this resultset on the client_id.

This does NOT work:

```
InsuranceProvider.where("effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers p group by client_id having p.client_id = insurance_providers.client_id)").client
```

resulting in a "NoMethodError":

```
undefined method `client' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_InsuranceProvider:0x007fe987725790>
```

UPDATE:

This is getting me the clients I need!

> Client.joins(:insurance_providers).where("insurance_providers.effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers p group by client_id having p.client_id = insurance_providers.client_id)")

But I can't get to the insurance_providers table. UGH! This is getting stickier....

UPDATE:

```
client.insurance_providers.order('effective_on DESC').first.copay
```

sometimes taking a break is all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in my controller, I have this:

```
@clients = Client.joins(:insurance_providers)
                 .where("insurance_providers.effective_on = (
                           SELECT MAX(effective_on) 
                           FROM insurance_providers p 
                           GROUP BY client_id 
                           HAVING p.client_id = insurance_providers.client_id
                        )")
```

Then in my view, I have this:

```
client.insurance_providers.order('effective_on DESC').first.copay
```

Comment: Very nice. Much less complicated.

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Teeg. I gave you a plus 1 for all the effort.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you were getting the `undefined method 'group'` error with the select in your first query, it shouldn't return anything at that point until you attempt to use one of the fields explicitly, or call `.load` or `.first`, etc.

`Maximum` is not the way to go either because that WILL immediately return the data, and its basically the same as saying in SQL "SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers", which is obviously not what you want.

<s>To answer your question directly, to summarize what you're looking to do, I believe you're trying to find the Insurance Provider with the hightest `effective_on` date, and then be able to view the client associated with that provider. Please correct me if I am mistaken.</s>

I think this will work:

```
insuranceProvider = 
    InsuranceProvider.where("effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers)")
                     .group(:client_id)
```

You shouldn't need anything else beyond that. Notice how I'm invoking the query on the `InsuranceProvider` model instead; Remember that with Rails, you can easily get the model object's associated records using your `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship descriptors.

Therefore, in order to get the associated `Client` model information, it is important that your `InsuranceProvider` class has a line that looks like `belongs_to :client`. This is required in this case, otherwise Rails doesn't know that this model relates to anything else. If you have that in there, then in order to get the `Client` information, all you simply need to do is

`client = insuranceProvider.client`

This will result in a second query which lazy-loads the client information for that insurance provider, and you're good to go.

**EDIT**

Based on the discussion in the comments, my original solution is not quite what you're looking for (and syntactically invalid for non-MySQL databases).

I answered a [similar question here once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19393589/877472) that is somewhat related to this, so maybe that information could be helpful.

Basically, what I think you'll need to do is grab your list of `Client`s, or grab your single `client` object, whatever you need to do, and invoke the association with a `.where` clause, like so:

```
client = Client.first # this is for illustration so that we have a client object to work with
insurance_provider = 
    client.insurance_providers
          .where("effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers WHERE client_id = ?", client.id)
```

Or, if you want to avoid having to inject the client.id manually, you can cause a dependent subquery, like so:

```
insurance_provider = 
    client.insurance_providers
          .joins(:client)
          .where("effective_on = (SELECT MAX(effective_on) FROM insurance_providers WHERE client_id = clients.id")
```

Comment: I think I tried what you'r suggesting at some point because I've seen this error before, but here's what I get when I try your `insuranceProvider =` line: `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "insurance_providers.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: @Ramy Right that makes sense. Actually I wasn't sure why the `group by` was in there in the first place, but I think you were using it to ensure you basically got only unique client ids. What happens if you remove the `group(:client_id)` entirely? Does that screw it up, or will it get you what you need? I'll update the answer if it works.

Comment: @Ramy Also, thinking about it more now, would it be technically (hypothetically) possible that multiple Insurance Providers have the exact same effective_on date? If so, how would you handle that situation? Would you just grab the first in that list in that scenario? If so, then you should be ok with ditching the `.group` and just invoking `.first`.

Comment: yeah, let me back up and explain. A client has_many insurance_providers but no more than one at a time. It represents coverage for a given time. So, once one provider has a newer effective_on date, that is the provider to user. It's basically to keep track of changing copay's.

Comment: removing the group by would just give me the most recent provider - that could be someone else's provider if that makes sense.

Comment: @Ramy Check out the update I just made. Maybe not quite what you were looking for, but it will get the job done. You can probably also find some ways to shorten or cache it too.

Comment: @Ramy I see the update in your question. Basically, I don't think you're going to be able to do it in one query using Active Record, unless you do it using raw SQL queries and deal with result sets, which I think is more work than its worth.